Question from Lance's book: norm of an element of algebraic tensor product of C*-algebras.
According to Lance's book of Hilbert modules,

For $r$ in $A\otimes_{\text{alg}}B,\;$the norm of $r$ is given by the following formula, in which $S(A),\;S(B)$ denote the state spaces of $A,B$:
$$||r||^2=\sup\left\{\frac{(\rho\otimes\sigma)(t^*r^*rt)}{(\rho\otimes\sigma)(t^*t)} \mid \rho\in S(A),\sigma\in S(B),t\in A\otimes_{\text{alg}}B,(\rho\otimes\sigma)(t^*t)\neq0 \right\}$$

I couldn't get that equation. Could someone give me a hint? Thanks!

Maybe I got that.

In general, there is more than one $C^\ast$-norm on the algebraic tensor product. So is your question why this particular formula defines a $C^\ast$-norm?
